# Unable to get information using RSSFeed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

To get the latest news from the client's website in the application I use RSSFeed.

when I use the URL

```
http://www.wiseadvice.co.nz/feed/rss/
```

information can be seen in the simulator

but when I use the URL

```
http://www.wiseadvice.co.nz/category/accounting-news-nz/
```

no information is available in the simulator.

Actually I want to arrange the information according to date and
in the first URL date is not available.

That's why I have to use another URL.

can anybody tell me why does this problem occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First URL returns valid `XML` file, second one returns whole `html` page.

Comment: How you parse data from these urls? I guess parse html page is a very terrible task. Or you just display it in webView?

Comment: fine I want to mention that when I run the app following log is displayed  "Failed to parse http://www.wiseadvice.co.nz/category/accounting-news-nz/"

Comment: thats amazing but how can you determine that first one is XML and second one is HTML? I dont know how to identify that? Can you please tell me how you have identified ?

Comment: Well, the issue is in files schemes. Open first URL in browser and choose View Source option (I use Chrome, View->Developer->View Source). First line of source indicates what is this. (<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="0.92">). For second this is - (<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US" >)